NodeODM orthomosaic stitching using GPU acceleration on an HPC
I am trying to run ODM on an HPC to generate an orthomosaic from a large amount (28k jpgs) of RGB imagery collected using a Mavic 3M. I set it up with an admin with root permission by:
module load usc git 
git clone
https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/NodeODM.git
cd NodeODM
salloc -p debug --ntasks=8
singularity pull
docker://opendronemap/odm:latest
exit 
module purge
cd NodeODM
singularity build --sandbox node/ apptainer.def
singularity run --writable node/
singularity shell --bind $PWD:/var/www NodeODM.sif
cd /var/www
npm install --production

I start it up using singularity run --bind $PWD:/var/www NodeODM.sif & then I navigate to http://localhost:3000/ on Firefox in my HPC’s terminal for the NodeODM GUI.
However, when I start a task, after images are uploaded I get the following error:
/task/b13871a6-220b-41ae-a72c-8191951a85e0/info?token= is unreachable

/task/b13871a6-220b-41ae-a72c-8191951a85e0/output is unreachable

I want to see if it works better with GPU acceleration instead, but I do not understand how to set that up for an HPC. The README.md file says:
docker run -p 3000:3000 --gpus all opendronemap/nodeodm:gpu

But I don’t understand how I would do that if I am running from a NodeODM.sif file instead of rom the docker file. How can I try GPU acceleration on an HPC?

You might try posting this question to the ODM community page.  https://community.opendronemap.org/

Hello, thanks. I had posted there too: https://community.opendronemap.org/t/gpu-acceleration-on-an-hpc-using-nodeodm/21181
